# Error: Invalid endian flag value encountered with Hibernate 6 and Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I am having some problems with Hibernate Spatial 6 with PostGIS and Spring Boot 3.0. This project I have taken and upgraded to SB 3.0 SNAPSHOT: https://github.com/murphye/spring-boot-postgis/tree/3.0

I am getting this error when I try to run a query:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
```

I am setting the dialect, but supposedly with Hibernate 6, this should no longer be necessary:

```
database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG10Dialect
```

Here is the column causing the issue:

```
    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")
    private Point geom;
```

and the query:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * from us_cities where ST_DistanceSphere(geom, :p) < :distanceM", nativeQuery = true)
```

Any thoughts on what the problem may be? It was working in Spring Boot 2.5. Thank you.

Comment: You are aware that Spring Boot 3.0 is still in development and hasn't released a final release yet? I doubt the issue is with Spring Boot but rather the Hibernate versions being used.

Comment: Yes, but 3.0 has had multiple milestones and is scheduled for GA in November. 3.0 will use Hibernate 6 which is a big change, and also likely the source of the problem, yes. However, at this point, this should work.

Comment: For Hibernate 6 you don't need to use spatial dialects. Just using the regular postgresql dialect will suffice, as long as you add the hibernate-spatial jar to the classpath. What is the OS for the database?

Comment: @KarelMaesen I did play with the dialects to just use PostgreSQL with no effect. This is MacOS M1 CPU.

Comment: Never tested on a MacOS M1. Could you paste more of the stacktrace (esp. the parts about Hibernate Spatial) so I can better identify the problem? (I'm the main developer of Hibernate Spatial).

Comment: @KarelMaesen Please see:  
  
https://github.com/murphye/spring-boot-postgis/blob/3.0/startup.txt  
https://github.com/murphye/spring-boot-postgis/blob/3.0/stacktrace.txt  
  
In the startup you can see that the PostgisDialectContributor is being applied.  
  
I don't know what to make of the stacktrace information. Please keep in mind, this problem only pops up with Spring Boot 3.0.

Comment: @KarelMaesen Here is the dependency tree which also may be of interest: https://github.com/murphye/spring-boot-postgis/blob/3.0/dependency-tree.txt

Comment: @KarelMaesen If you see my answer below, I was able to get it work.

You have some broken docs here (Unresolved directive). https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I got this working. I had to make some tweaks but the main change was using locationtech packages rather than vividsolutions. I believe this change may be required for Hibernate 6.

I also had to use a fork of jackson-datatype-jts that works with locationtech.

I was also able to comment out some Spring Boot config (such as database-platform) that is no longer needed with Hibernate 6.

Code is here on the 3.0 branch: https://github.com/murphye/spring-boot-postgis/tree/3.0